# Drupal 8 and colorbox

Tags: javascript, drupal, colorbox, drupal-8

does anybody has a practical experience with setting up the Colorbox in Drupal 8? I'm trying to have the "common" functionality so after I click the image thumbnail it will be opened withing overlay Colorbox window.

I have installed everything I'v found related to the Colorbox but no success.

In the page code I can see:

```
<a href="/path/to/img.jpg" class="colorbox">
```

Also set of the colorbox related JS files:

```
 <script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=2.1.4"></script>   
<script src="/libraries/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js?v=8.0.5"></script>
    <script src="/modules/colorbox/js/colorbox.js?v=8.0.5"></script>
    <script src="/modules/colorbox/styles/plain/colorbox_style.js?v=8.0.5"></script>
    <script src="/modules/colorbox_inline/js/colorbox_inline.js?o3m4ww"></script>
    <script src="/modules/colorbox_load/js/colorbox_load.js?o3m4ww"></script>
```

All files are at the location as stated in src attributes above. Also Firebud doesn't show any JS related issue.

But if I click that A element the image is loaded as a new page without any Colorbox overlay :(

Thanks

Comment: I tried this on a clean install and it works properly; did you try changing the theme, or re-submitting the admin settings form on `/admin/config/media/colorbox`?

Comment: Good point - I've noticed that under Bartik theme it works fine. There is one more class in the A element but when I add the same class using Firebug under my therem it doesn't work. 
It's strane as based on the tempalte debug the field in my template si fully create using colorbox. 
I'm going to investigate further.

Comment: OK - deep investigation resulted in fact that it works in each theme but mine. I have sub theme derived from Mayo. I'm not aware of any major changes there. I did compare html code of the page created under both themes and no significant difference found (same attributes on that A and IMG elements, same JS files loaded).

There is one key difference - in Firebug I can see that additionl _cboxElement_ class added to the "working" A element - but it's not there if I open HTML source of the page.

Comment: I would re-create the base of the child theme (copy/paste element by element) and after each test to see if the issue is still present. There must be something that interferes with it.

Comment: Yes, I've realised that key class _cboxElement_ is being added "onthefly" normaly (after page is rendered) but not in my template. I'll have to do this kind of debugging as you've suggested.

Comment: This kind of debugging sucks, but you'll get slightly better at it at least. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

So finaly - thanks to comments from  Aram Boyajyan who pointed me to check the other themes where it worked, I've realized I should go back to school. Or at least back to good old times where were no CMSes or frameworks and we were supposed to pass the code throught the w3c validator to proudly display that cool icon about our site compliance ;-)

If I'd do that once I've updated each template file it would save me 3 nights of investigation.

So to summarize - due to missing some of the closing div elements Colorbox were not able to update corresponding elements properly and therefore were not working as expecte.

That's it.